# Echo Arrays in Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, echo

I have an Array with mutltiple Arrays in it. I tried to echo each of them but I get "Array" instead of the values which are saved inside of each Arrays.

My Array looks like this:

```
$arrays = [['test1','test2'],['test3','test4']];

foreach($arrays as $array) {
       echo $array, '<br>';
}
```

I get:

```
Array
Array
```

instead of

```
test1,test2
test3,test4
```

Comment: php array should use `[]` instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not printing the content of inner arrays - try this:

```
$arrays = [['test1','test2'],['test3','test4']];

foreach($arrays as $array) {
    echo implode(',', $array) . '<br>';
}
```

Oh, and why not just `print_r($arrays)`?

Comment: I get the error TypeError: this.toArray is not a function

Comment: @Preprocezzor This is due to syntax error of using `{}` instead of `[]`.  I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($arrays); 
echo "</pre>";
```

**update**

Convinient way to use this is to make shortcut in your `IDE`. For example in NetBeans when I want to `var_dump` something, I just type `vdp` and press `Tab`. You will find `NetBeans` shortcuts under `Tools->Options->Editor->Code Templates`.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible way to print your data:

```
foreach($arrays as $array) {
    foreach($array as $value) {
        echo $value . ",";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r($array)`

It prints all the inner arrays within an array

Comment: True, but this used for debugging purposes only. Not an answer OP is looking for.